# Upon boot, NOOBS GUI only stays onscreen for approximately 15 seconds

Tags: noobs

Upon boot, NOOBS GUI only stays onscreen for approximately 15 seconds, and then the Command Line Interface appears.

How do I get back to the GUI, and how do I prevent the system from going to the CLI in the future?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: With `startx`. And you can add this to your `.bash_profile` to autologin to X on startup (as per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#Autostart_X_at_login)
Or by installing a displaymanager like LightDM

Comment: Thank you.  startx did indeed get me back to the GUI, and it seems to be staying there and not reverting to the CLI.  I do not understand why I have to do this extra step now.  Previously the system would boot straight to the GUI and stay there. (???)

Comment: I have no idea honestly. Did you remove/change some dotfiles in your home folder or tinkered with `config.txt`?

Comment: No sir.  I am a NOOB just like the software, so I don't even know how to access those files.  It must have happened during a recent power loss, I guess (???)

Comment: `ls -al` shows you all your files in current directory (the ones starting with a dot are hidden files (aka dotfiles)). It could be that something got corrupted if you didn't turn it off correctly (Yey sd-cards :D). Try reflashing and see if it persists.

Comment: OK. I will have to work on that when I have time.  I appreciate your responses and help!

Comment: Can I simply add that command you indicated in your first reply? I am trying to understand that wiki you linked....  I appreciate your replies and your help!

Comment: "NOOBS GUI only stays onscreen for approximately 15 seconds, and then" … depends what OS you installed!

Comment: @Milliways Ah I see, I did not know that, never bothered with NOOBS. So no need for reflashing than.
And yeah mwolfod, you can just add that snippet to your `.bash_profile`. But there will probably be another way aswell. Try `sudo raspi-config` and look around in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is

```
startx
```

or

```
xorg start
```

But my suggestion is you change the config.txt and startup settings for this to avoid this hassle.

Comment: Thanks fellas for the continued support.  It is very helpful for a Linux Noob, using NOOB.

Comment: @mwolfod  Then please select the answer and end this topic please. Thank you.

Comment: Ok.  Done.  I didn't know the proper protocol on this Forum.  Thank you and thanks to all.